# PhpMyAdmin - Changing charset

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, content-encoding

How may I change the database/Tables/Attributes charset using PhpMyAdmin (No SQL statement, only hand-and-mouse actions) ? I only see the option for the Collation (inter-classement).

Comment: Here's a video showing how to change the database collation using phpMyAdmin https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dk6jsYpClp0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the collation is what you want to do.

Collations are rules regarding the sort order and search sensitivity. Every collation is based on a certain character set. There is no way to specify the character set separately from the collation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for changing character set and collation of your databases and tables through phpMyAdmin or from the command line.

Following site explain how to change character set and collation in brief:

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403914/default-mysql-character-set-and-collation